# Send/receive or refresh inbox on native email client

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, email

Is there such an option for the native email client built into Froyo?

For example, I might send myself a document to the phone via email, and it won't come through straight away. Sometimes I need that option to check for new emails.

There's no obvious refresh option in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into the Mail client, go into the mailbox you want to check the mail for, then press Menu while you're looking at the Inbox, there should be a Refresh option on the menu bar.

That definitely seemed to go back to the server and check for new mail when I tried it with the Hotmail account I've got set up in there just now, as it found the message I'd sent a minute before.

Comment: I have only: delete, list by, move to folder, view mode and account manager. Have Samsung messed with the Email client?

Comment: Mine's a Galaxy S running the Samsung Froyo release, so we should both be seeing the same thing either way. When I press Menu in an Inbox I see Compose, Refresh, Search, Accounts, List By and More (which has Account Settings, Text Size and View Mode).  I've only got Hotmail and Yahoo accounts on mine, and I think both these use ActiveSync, are you using POP/SMTP servers as it's possible these may have different options?

Comment: I'm using IMAP. That must be the explanation, although it seems odd not to have a refresh option for it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is the account you're using listed in `Settings | Accounts & sync`?

If so, you should be able to select the account then choose `Menu | Sync now`.